# How to change the default font size in plotly?

Tags: plotly, font-size, plotly-python

I generally would like to have large font sizes in plotly figures.

Is there a way to do that globally with themes? And how can I do that for a single figure after creating it e.g. with

```
fig = px.scatter(...)
```

Comment: The ability to directly change the default font size does not appear to be provided. The way to deal with this is to create an original [template](https://plotly.com/python/templates/#representing-themes-with-template-objects) and set it at the beginning. See this answer:[How to set general font for graph with Plotly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58376421/how-to-set-general-font-for-graph-with-plotly)